# Why different presentation of client area?

Tags: ubuntu, awesome, theme

I am using awesome with on ubuntu 12.04. I changed the theme  with myunity Now my Gnome applications are presented white and all other in the dark theme. Why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The theme was not set, so you get a ugly look.

Basically there's two options, set a default GTK2 (~/.gtkrc-2.0) and GTK3 (~/.config/gtk3/settings.ini) theme, or simply launch the settings daemon, IIRC `gnome-settings-daemon`, which would set the theme from your gconf.

Comment: Atm i have to start it manually, but I did it before.